# ORA-00972 identifier is too long Oracle procedure

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a **Oracle procedure**, its return query

```
SELECT CODE "Կադաստրային ծածկագիր", ENTAKAYANI "Ենթակայան"
FROM ELECTRIC_ENTAKAYAN_500 
WHERE SDO_RELATE(GEOM,SDO_GEOM.SDO_BUFFER(
                 MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 2400000,
                 MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(8451136.4,4451591.2,NULL),
                  NULL, NULL), 2, 0.005)
                ,'mask=ANYINTERACT')='TRUE'
  AND rownum <= 10;
```

and problem this length("Կադաստրային ծածկագիր") = 20, Oracle max size length filed 30 symbol, but my string Armenian languages its > 30 symbol.

How to find an another solution?

Comment: You might want to always use English/Latin names for your tables and columns.  This would also make it easier for others to read your code.

Comment: I need only Armenian

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? Please tag your question properly.

Comment: oracle, I am sorry

Comment: This is not a procedure, otherwise you would need `INTO ...` clause. What is your purpose? Why do you need Armenian characters as identifier?

Comment: It is a procedure for 100%, I am using Armenian, cause I'm live in Armenia and my client wants just Armenian characters, but Armenian language is not a problem because I can use long word in English also, so I would like you to suggest me an another solution because language is not a reason for that error.

Comment: why don't you do what everyone does in English (and Swedish and German...) and just use abbreviated versions of the column names?  The column aliases are only visible to developers (if that statement is contained within PL/SQL).  If you're worried they won't understand the abbreviation then put the full column name in a comment

Comment: and I guess the reason for the error is the max length is 30 *bytes* (not characters) and Armenian uses a multi-byte characterset.

Comment: @ChristianPalmer please tell me the reason why he has to use the list of some restricted languages?

Comment: Why do you need such customized identifiers? Again, what is the purpose of your code? And again, without some surroundings or an `INTO ...` this is not a PL/SQL procedure.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan he can use any language he likes.  The point I was making is that there is a limit that applies to all languages.  If in English I want a column alias of total_number_of_invoices_this_month then I need to cut it down to something shorter.  So does anyone working in German, or Swedish, or indeed Armenian

Comment: @ChristianPalmer ok, as you told, the main point should be related to the abbreviation only.

Comment: Or switch databases.  Oracle is the only database (at least that I regularly use) that has this archaic limit on identifier lengths.  It has been a problem for *decades*.

Comment: @GordonLinoff There is no need to switch databases (just upgrade to 12.2 and enable long identifiers).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Oracle 12cR2 you could use identifiers that are up to 128 bytes.

[Database Object Naming Rules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA):

> **If COMPATIBLE is set to a value of 12.2 or higher, then names must be from 1 to 128 bytes long with these exceptions:**
>
> - Names of databases are limited to 8 bytes.
> - Names of disk groups, pluggable databases (PDBs), rollback segments, tablespaces, and tablespace sets are limited to 30 bytes.
>
> If an identifier includes multiple parts separated by periods, then each attribute can be up to 128 bytes long. Each period separator, as well as any surrounding double quotation marks, counts as one byte. For example, suppose you identify a column like this:
>
> ```
> "schema"."table"."column"
> ```
>
> The schema name can be 128 bytes, the table name can be 128 bytes, **and the column name can be 128 bytes.** Each of the quotation marks and periods is a single-byte character, so the total length of the identifier in this example can be up to 392 bytes.

Please keep in mind that `byte` != `character`.

```
SELECT /*csv*/ 1 AS "Կադաստրային ծածկագիր" FROM dual;
/*
"Կադաստրային ծածկագիր"
1
*/
```

And counting characters/bytes:

```
SELECT 
  length('ադաստրային ծածկագիր 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890') AS char#
,lengthb('ադաստրային ծածկագիր 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890') AS bytes#
FROM dual;
/*
     CHAR#     BYTES#
---------- ----------
      120        138
*/
```